# The use of "-en" in a specific phrase

Tags: grammatical-case, possessive-pronoun, suffix

The phrase "meinen Befehlen" which means "my order" is used in a sentence from the movie Untergang.

From other sentences I know "mein" means "my" and "Befehl" means "order" without the "-en" at the end of both words.

I tried to search up what the "-en" mean by Googling but it seems the suffix has like 10 different usages. I would guess "Befehlen" means plural form of "Befehl" but I am not really sure, and I have no idea why "meinen" is here instead of "mein".

Might be a stupid question but this comes from one with no prior knowledge of the German language. The transcript might be wrong so if this phrase does not make sense with the "-en" please let me know as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
As required in the comment, the whole sentence is the following:

> "Wer sind Sie, dass Sie es wagen, sich **meinen Befehlen** zu widersetzen?".

My confusion is on

1. is "Befehlen" the plural form of "Befehl" or does it mean something else?
2. what's the difference if "mein" is used instead of "meinen"?

Comment: *Meinen Befehlen* is Dative of *meine Befelhle*. You should at least post a whole sentence when asking for meaning.

Comment: @Olafant I have edited the post to include the whole sentence and clarify my question.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. As you might have overseen in Olafant's comment, he wrote "Meinen *B*efehlen" instead of "meinen *b*efehlen". The difference makes the word class: noun or verb. And your example goes to "noun". While you translate it correct with "order" instead of "to order"/"to command", I've just the feeling that your confusion with your search results starts here. Because I'd expect some conjugation table as solution. With cases and stuff.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm He also wrote *Befelhle*.

Comment: @xehpuk That's a typo. It's *Befehle*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus I know. My point was that "*B*efehlen" could have been a typo, too.

Comment: @xehpuk: I'm sorry, I'm unable to find "Befelhle" or "Befehle" when I open the edit history and use a website search for the question. Anyway, now this typo is no longer present. I wrote *B*efehlen to pinpiont the capital letter.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm It's in the first comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all: to figure out the meaning by using translation apps, you need to take care of right spelling. In German there is a big difference between *befehlen* and *Befehlen*. The former is a verb. The latter is a noun. As I can tell from your question, you know it's a noun here. The sentence that you are asking about is:

> Wer sind **S**ie, dass **S**ie es wagen, sich meinen **B**efehlen zu widersetzen?

You see, there is already more than one problem here. That's why I really doubt, that learning from subtitles is a good idea. At least it should be subtitles of very high quality then.

The whole sentence

> Wer sind Sie, dass Sie es wagen, sich meinen Befehlen zu widersetzen?

means something like

> Who are you, to dare to defy my orders.

So: *meinen Befehlen* translates to *my orders* here. But now you are trying to find out, why there is an *-en* in *mein**en*** and *Befehl**en*** by searching for the the meaning of that suffix. And that shows very clearly, that your approach is kind of hairy.

It's about cases of objects.

*Meine**n** Befehle**n*** is dative of *meine Befehle*. *Mein**e** Befehl**e*** is plural of *mein Befehl*.

*Sich zu widersetzen* means *to defy* <sup>1</sup>, and the object *my order* or whatever it is that someone is defying, has to be in dative case. <sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1 literal meaning is something like *to counter-set oneself* <sup>2</sup>

2 thanks to @HalvarF for pointing that out in the comments.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for explaining about the cases. I think I now understand it now. "meine Befehle" is the plural form of "mein Befehl", and the "n" at the end is there because of the sentence structure where the phrase is placed. Could you at least tell me if I am correct or not?

Comment: That's correct. "sich zu widersetzen" means "to defy" (literal meaning is something like "to counter-set oneself"), and the object "my order"or whatever it is that someone is defying, has to be in dative case.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @cr001 You're right. Please see my edit.

Comment: @HalvarF Thanks for poining that out. I added it into the answer so it doesn't get lost.

Comment: @cr001: No, it does not depend on the placement of the phrase in the sentence. "Wer sind Sie, dass Sie es wagen, sich zu widersetzen meinen Befehlen?" would be possible too, or "Wer sind Sie, dass Sie es wagen, meinen Befehlen sich zu widersetzen?" It's the case which determines the endings, compare to: "Wer sind Sie, dass Sie es wagen, meine Befehle zu ignorieren?" Same placement, but missing the reflexive "sich". "Sich wem zu widersetzen?" vs. "Wen oder was zu ignorieren?".

Comment: @cr001 it's not where due to where the phrase is placed but due to the grammatical case of the object in the sentence. Endings are different for different grammatical cases